# Why can't I print a debug message in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to follow the Chapter 6.2 Constructing a Rational in the book **Programming in Scala**.
But I have problem when trying to do this.

This is the **test.scala**:

```
class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) 
{
  println("Created "+n+"/"+d)
}
```

So I first type the following in my terminal window:

```
user$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_73).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

And then use `:load test.scala`

```
scala> :load test.scala
Loading test.scala...
defined class Rational
<console>:12: error: not found: value n
        println("Created "+n+"/"+d)
                           ^
<console>:12: error: not found: value d
        println("Created "+n+"/"+d)
                                 ^
```

I am expecting when I type in `new Rational(1, 2)`.

```
Created 1/2
res0: Rational = Rational@90110a
```

But the result is

```
res0: Rational = Rational@9e89d68
```

The interpreter only returns the second line. How can I print out this debug message?

BTW, I am using Mac OS.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

---

Updated

This is the right way of doing it.

```
class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) {
  println("Created "+n+"/"+d)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Semicolon inference is what's ruining your day.

The Scala compiler interprets

```
class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) 
{   println("Created "+n+"/"+d)
 }
```

as

```
class Rational(n: Int, d: Int); 
{   println("Created "+n+"/"+d);
 }
```

Oops!

Try this instead:

```
class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) {
   println("Created "+n+"/"+d)
}
```

The compiler no longer infers a semicolon at the end of the first line, because the open curly brace signals that there is more to come.

It should work much better.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Oh, it's quite different in Scala. I thought the position of "{" does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

The reason of error is that your code in test.scala file is actually evaluated as two separate statements.
It is so because in this case line separator is treated as semicolon.

Semicolon inference rules:
http://jittakal.blogspot.com/2012/07/scala-rules-of-semicolon-inference.html

If you change it to (one line):

```
class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) { println("Created "+n+"/"+d) }
```

or better:

```
class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) { 
    println("Created "+n+"/"+d) 
}
```

then it will behave as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

[Starting in Scala 2.10.0, Scala offers a new mechanism to create strings from your data: String Interpolation.](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)

Pay attention to the 's' before quotation mark (")

```
val name = "James"
println(s"Hello, $name")  // Hello, James
```